# SqlDataReader C#, SQL Server 2005, VS 2008

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to select `food_ItemName` and `food_UnitPrice` from `t_Food` table in SQL Server 2005 using C# and VS 2008.

I have the following code:

```
        private SqlConnection connection;

        private void GetDatabaseConnection()
        {
            string connectionString = @"Server = RZS-F839AD139AA\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated  Security = SSPI; Database = HotelCustomerManagementDatabase";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
        }

        public Food PopulateFoodItemListview()
        {
           GetDatabaseConnection();
            string selectFoodItemQuery = @"SELECT food_ItemName, food_UnitPrice FROM t_Food";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectFoodItemQuery, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            Food food = new Food();
            List foodList = new List();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                food.ItemName.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                MessageBox.Show("ItemName: "+ food.ItemName);
                food.UnitPrice.Add(reader.GetDouble(1));
                MessageBox.Show("UnitPrice: " + food.UnitPrice);

            }
            connection.Close();
            return food;
        }
```

And in `Food` class I have the following code:

```
    public class Food
    {
        private List itemName = new List();
        private List unitPrice = new List();
        private double itemUnit;
        private Customer foodCustomer = new Customer();

        public List ItemName
        {
            get { return itemName; }
            set { itemName = value ; }
        }

        public List UnitPrice
        {
            get { return unitPrice; }
            set { unitPrice = value; }
        }

        public double ItemUnit
        {
            get { return itemUnit; }
            set { itemUnit = value; }
        }
        public double GetItemPrice(double itemUnit, double unitPrice)
        {
            double itemPrice = itemUnit*unitPrice;
            return itemPrice;
        }
}
```

In messageBox it supposed to show Rice, Mutton, Beef and their price 50, 100, 150. But it showhing  `` ItemName: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `` and
`` ItemName: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double] ``

Whats the problem?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is your SQL query returning the desired data?

Comment: Just a note, it is good practice to use generic collections when you can.  It's better practice to not provide setters on properties that expose those collections.

Comment: @towhidulbashar - welcome to stackoverflow.  Just to let you know you may want to go through all of your questions and mark an answer you used as being accepted.  The community usually is at work but the users of the community still make time to answer questions on this site.  So it is definately the right thing to do is mark all of your questions that are solved with an accepted answer.

Comment: @JonH :: I chose the accepted answer by clicking on tick mark. Is there anything I need to do to mark my question as a solved problem?
Actually I'm new in Stackoverflow community. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify:

```
private List<string> itemName;
```

That way when you add a name you can do:

```
itemName = new List<string>();
itemName.Add("Pizza");
```

The problem you are noticing is food.itemName is simply a list not a string.
So you can get the string from a list by : `myList[someIndex],` that is your List object followed by the index of the item in your list.

Once you fill your food itemName list you should be able to foreach it:

```
foreach(string f in food.itemName)
 MessageBox.Show(f);
```

**Aside from this I am a bit concerned with the wording of this class.**  If a Food object represents one entity of food then why is itemName and price `list` members of this class?  They should simply be properties of type `string` and `double` respectively.  When you create a food object the object contains a name and a price.

```
public sealed class Food
{
 public string itemName {get; set;}
 public double unitPrice {get; set;}
}
```

Here is how you could do it:

```
public sealed class Food 
 {
     public string itemName {get; set;}
     public double unitPrice {get; set;}
     public double itemUnit {get; set;}
     public double getItemPrice() { return itemUnit * unitPrice; }
     public Food() : this("unknown food", 0);
     public Food(string item, double price) { itemName = item; unitPrice = price; }

     //you might want to rethink your customer object as well.  Are
     //you associating one customer with one item of food ?
 }
```

And how to use the class:

```
 public sealed class MyUsageOfFood
 {
 public static void main() {
  List<Food> f = new List<Food>;
  f.Add(new Food("Pizza", 1.50));
  f.Add(new Food("Hamburger", 2.00));

  foreach(food t in f)
      MessageBox.Show(t.itemName);
 }}
```

Comment: I'm equally concerned. See my answer.

Comment: @Chirs :: Yea you are right. Im new in OOP. So I cant catch the concept of FOOD class.

@MusiGenesis:: I see you answer. Thanks for your details answer.

Comment: Just curious: why make these classes sealed?

Comment: @MusiGenesis - No reason I tend to do that a lot of examples here.  I'm a fan of Richter and generally if you don't plan to extend the class then seal it.  But you could do without it.

Answer (score 4):

food.ItemName is a List, not a string, so the ToString() returns the type.  What you want instead is:

```
food.ItemName[food.ItemName.Count - 1]
```

and same for UnitPrice:

```
food.UnitPrice[food.UnitPrice.Count - 1].ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Food` class is meant to represent a single item of food, so your `itemName` and `unitPrice` members should be of type `string` and `double`, respectively (not `List`, which is used to store multiple values).

Then, `PopulateFoodItemListview` should return `List<Food>` (not `Food`).  Inside your `reader.Read()` loop, you should create a new `Food` instance, populate it with the appropriate values from the database, and then add it to your `List<Food>` collection (which is then returned at the end of the method).

**Update:** Like this:

```
public List<Food> PopulateFoodItemListview()
{
    GetDatabaseConnection();
    string selectFoodItemQuery = @"SELECT food_ItemName, food_UnitPrice FROM t_Food";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectFoodItemQuery, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    List<Food> foods = new List<Food>();
    List<string> foodList = new List<string>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Food food = new Food();
        food.ItemName = reader.GetString(0);
        MessageBox.Show("ItemName: "+ food.ItemName);
        food.UnitPrice = reader.GetDouble(1);
        MessageBox.Show("UnitPrice: " + food.UnitPrice);
        foods.Add(food);
    }
    connection.Close();
    return foods;
}

public class Food
{
    private string itemName = "";
    private double unitPrice = 0.0;
    private double itemUnit;

    private Customer foodCustomer = new Customer();

    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return itemName; }
        set { itemName = value ; }
    }

    public double UnitPrice
    {
        get { return unitPrice; }
        set { unitPrice = value; }
    }

    public double ItemUnit
    {
        get { return itemUnit; }
        set { itemUnit = value; }
    }
    public double GetItemPrice(double itemUnit, double unitPrice)
    {
        double itemPrice = itemUnit*unitPrice;
        return itemPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed adding a food object to the `List<food> foods` object.
Otherwise you'd return an empty list.

Comment: Actually I'm writing this code to show food name & their unit price in a ListView. But if I return "foods" which is a List of "food"  then how I show them in a ListView from another class?

And why u write this  "List<string> foodList = new List<string>();"

Comment: @towhidulbashar: dumping a `List<Food>` collection into a `ListView` is easy - just do a `foreach` iteration and add a `ListViewItem` to your `ListView` for each `Food` object in the collection. BTW, I have no idea how `foodList` got changed to `List<string>` in my code - I think Visual Studio did it when I pasted in your original code. `foodList` doesn't get used anywhere anyway, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @ MusiGenesis :: Ok, I displayed it on ListView but only the values for the last "Food" object is added. That means I can't added new row in ListView. How I will add a new roe in ListView?

Comment: @ MusiGenesis :: I'm back again just to say that at last I can display them in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

ItemName and UnitPrice are List objects, not individual items. When you pass objects to the MessageBox function, it will call ToString() on the object to get a displayable string. ToSting() on a List returns the strings you are seeing. You should use indexes to get to items in the list:

```
MessageBox(ItemName(1));
```

or

```
MessageBox(UnitPrice(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that food.Item name returns a `List<string>` and you are making the implicit call to `List<string>::ToString` which returns details on the type. You should either request the last entered item as `food.ItemName[food.ItemName.Count - 1]` or you could iterate through all of the items in the list to output all of the names/prices.